# Batch: find all files with exclude part of the name

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, filenames

I need to find all * .avi files (even in subfolders). But I want to exclude files with specific part of the name (* demux.avi). Something like this:

```
FOR /R %%g IN (*.avi) DO ( 
   if "%%g"=="*demux.avi" (      - THIS PART IS WRONG
       echo "%%g" excluded
  ) else (
       echo "%%g"
   )
)
```

I expect results:

> file1.avi 
>   file1 demux.avi excluded 
>   file2.avi 
>   **

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
FOR /F %%g IN ('dir /b /s "*.avi"^|find /i /v "demux"') DO ( whatever )
```

We are basically saying look for all avi files in this folder and subfolders and pipe them to find. 
Use finds /V switch that finds all lines NOT containing "demux" and run your command on them.

Answer (score 0):

Like this :

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.avi') do (echo %%a | find "demux" && echo %%a [Excluded] || echo %%a [OK])
```

In place of echo %%a [Excluded] or echo %%a [OK] you can do what you want (`DEL, REN,MOVE,...`)

Edit :

To just have the name of the file when your using `/S` option of `DIR`

```
@echo off&cls
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s/b/a-d *.avi') do (echo %%~na | find "demux" && echo %%~na [Excluded] || echo %%~na [OK])
```

Comment: I found another problem. I have to use dir with parameter /s for searching all sub folders. But it returns full patch e.g. C:\work\video.avi. I would like to get just part of the name - between slash and dot "video". How to do it, length is variable.